# What does the verb 'lisser' mean in this sentence?

Tags: traduction

I have come across the following sentence and cannot quite make out a satisfying translation for how 'lisser' is used here. The dictionary says 'to smooth, to even out' but I do not think that this fits here.

*Elle ajoute aussi que la fiabilité des informations est mise en danger par les applications qui lissent arbitrairement le Nutri-Score.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning is the one you found in a dictionary.

The applications referred to are criticized because they smooth (i.e. make less relevant) the Nutri-Score by weighting it with other metrics or whatever algorithm.

[image]

Source: Mathilde Touvier [Magazine de l'Inserm - n° 44](https://fr.calameo.com/read/005154450ea0796c65b1c)

Comment: So, is it meant in a literal sense in this case, i.e. that the score is mathematically smoothed out? Or is it metaphorical?

Comment: It might be either but *lissent à leur façon* is more a metaphor for *they blur the asperities (the bad Nutri-Score values) their own way*, they fiddle with these numbers.